# date_taken in flickr api returning 'none' - how to extract date taken?

Tags: python-2.7, date, flickr

I am trying to extract the date taken metadata from the flickr api. When I print the metadata it returns the url, the name of the owner and 'none' where a date should be.

I know there are dates taken associated with these photos because I can see them displayed on the pages in the group pool.

How can I retrieve a date?

```
import flickr_api 
flickr_api.set_keys(api_key = 'your-flickr-api-key', api_secret = 'your-flickr-api-secret')
from flickr_api.api import flickr
def findurl(stuff):
photolist = stuff['photos']['photo']
for thing in photolist:
    print thing['url_o']
    print thing.get('date_taken')
    print thing.get('ownername')
stuff = flickr_api.api.call_api(
    method='flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos',
    group_id = '1156559@N21', 
    extras = 'date_taken, ownername, url_o', 
    page = page,
    per_page = 100
    )
findurl(stuff)
```

Comment: Are you printing thing.get('date_taken') before calling the flickr api call?

Comment: It is also possible to scrub the image metadata (like date taken) if the uploader doesn't want that to upload. There are valid reasons for wanting to clear the metadata, for example, my camera adds my name and e-mail to the photo, and it is easier to drop all the metadata then selectively clearing just that (if I cared, which I don't, but some people may).

Answer (score 0):

Is this not just a case of the wrong identifier being referenced? Testing the [groups.pools.getPhotos in the API Explorer](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos), I see the date taken being returned as `datetaken` (no underscore). When specifying in `extras` there *is* an underscore, but when reading a photo result there is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating through your photos lets say u have an integer called counter.

This would access `datetaken print(photos['photo'][counter]['datetaken'])`
because flickrapi returns sth like this

```
flickrApi({ "photos": {"page: "1" "pages": "1", "perpage": 100, "total": "29983680", 
"photo": [ {"id" : "owner" and so on blabla also "datetaken" }]
```

sth along these lines, you can see that we have a dictionaries within a list which is within a dictionary of another dictionary or sth like that <.<

basically u go through tiers of access points just structure it in your mind

`photos['page']` would return the page

`photos['total']` would return total pages

`photos['photo']` returns a photo object with all its values like id and height/width or whatever the object has various attributes and there are also multiple objects, its a list of objects, so you need to iterate through it to get all, since we want a specific attribute we need to tell him which photo he should take it from, therefor the counter
You can iterate through it without counter but then you can't access the attributes.

Make sure counter starts with 0 and counts up after u access `datetaken`, otherwise you miss that one photo in the start.

Short Answer:

`photos['photo][counter]['datetaken']`